# json getting children's children nodes hierarchy

Tags: d3.js, nodes, parent, hierarchy

I am struggling to get the children's children in this json code, any help would be much appreciated!
Basically I have a 3 layered sunburst chart in D3, I want to highlight the node currently hovered on, as well as it's children and the outer ring children. Current code works but only highlighting nearest children:

```
  function getChildren(node){
  var children = [];
   children.push(node);
        //iterate through the children
        node.children.forEach(function(child){
            //add to the child list if target id is not same
            children.push(child);
            
            children.push(child.children);

 ////Below is my attempt to add second layer of child elements but it isn't working as planned:

            child.children.forEach(function(innerChild){
            if (innerChild.children) {
                children.push(innerChild.children);
                                      }
                                                        });
                                             });
            return children

      }
```

The hierarchy structure is as follows:

```
  result = _(dataArr)
              .groupBy(x => x["Inner circle"])
              .map((value1, key) => ({
                name: key, count: sum(value1), children: _(value1)
                  .groupBy(x => x["Middle circle"])
                  .map((value2, key) => ({
                    name: key, count: sum(value2), children: _(value2)
                      .groupBy(x => x["Outer circle"])
                      .map((value3, key) => ({
                        name: key, count: sum(value3), children: _(value3)
                        .groupBy(x => x["Label"])
                        .map((value4, key) => ({ name: key, count: outersum(value4) , children: [] }))

                          .value()
                  }))
                  .value()
              }))
              .value()
            }))
            .value();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt4ge.png)

Answer (score 0):

In its current state, you're 2 layers deep. Hence the missing outer ring.

`children.push(node);` adds the json object to the `children` array in its entirety.

`children.push(child);` adds all the children of the json object to the `children` array. This is the first or inner layer.

`children.push(child.children);` adds all the children of the inner circle. So this is the second layer.

The missing code, to be added after the previous line:

```
child.children.forEach(function(innerChild){
  if (innerChild.children) {
    children.push(innerChild.children);
  }
});
```

will add the third layer to your array.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense! I tried to incorporate the code however still not getting the outer layer: function getChildren(node){
  var children = [];
   children.push(node);
        //iterate through the children
        node.children.forEach(function(child){
            //add to the child list if target id is not same
            children.push(child);
 child.children.forEach(function(innerChild){
   if (innerChild.children) {
     children.push(innerChild.children);
   }
 });
  });
            return children

      }

Comment: Are the outer ring's elements still not added to the array? Could you add to your question (a part of the relevant json with) one node with all its children?

Comment: I just updated the code in the question with what I have now - maybe there is something I am missing still - The two first nodes are highlighted but not the third outer layer ( see image attached to question) Thanks for you help!

Comment: I think it is complaining about the nested forEach loops. I am getting the error "javaScriptConsoleMessage: message=Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined sourceId=http://localhost:8005/script.js lineNumber=271"